# Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

a) If H is normal in G then $ C_G(H)$ is normal subgroup of G

b) $ If K ≤ H ≤ G $ and K is normal in G then $ H/K ⊆ Z ( G / K ) $ if and only if $[H,G] ⊆ K$

I proved a):

Let $g_1 ∈ C_G(H) $, i.e , $ g_1h=hg_1$ for all h in H. Let $g ∈ G$, we want to show that $g^{-1}g_1g ∈ C_G(H)$ ,i.e, $ (g^{-1}g_1g)h = h (g^{-1}g_1g)$ for all h in H.

Fixed $h∈H$ since H is normal in G, $g^{-1}hg∈H$, i.e, $gh_1=hg$ or $ g^{-1}h_1= hg^{-1}$ then

$(g^{-1}g_1g)h = g^{-1}g_1(gh) =g^{-1}g_1(h_1g) =g^{-1}(g_1h_1)g = g^{-1}(h_1g_1)g= (g^{-1}h)g_1g=(hg^{-1})g_1g = h(g^{-1}g_1g)$

then $g^{-1}g_1g ∈ C_G(H)$

Someone can help me with b) i can not solve it.

Comment: A slicker proof of a) is to note that $C_G(H)$ is the kernel of the homomorphism from $G$ to $\rm{Aut}(H)$ where each $g\in G$ is sent to conjugation by $g$ (which is an automorphism of $H$ since $H$ is normal). This also immediately gives you a good way to understand the quotient $G/C_G(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $A$ is central in $B$ if and only if $[A,B]$ is trivial.

($A$ central $\Leftrightarrow$ things in $A$ commute with things in $B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ all commutators $[a,b]$ are trivial)

Consider with $A=H/K$, $B=G/K$. Note $[H/K,G/K]=[H,G]K/K$.